# Date error in php upgrade

Tags: php

The Following code i use in my scripts for getting the date

```
<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("tommorow")); ?> 

<?php $tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+1, date("Y")); echo "".date("Y-m-d", $tomorrow); ?>
```

now i get the error in php 5

```
It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set your timezone at the top of your script, for example, for London:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.1 made a few changes to the `mktime` function such that it will throw an error if the timezone is not set. You can read the documentation for it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: <?php
// Set the default timezone to use. Available as of PHP 5.1
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
?> working thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every call to a [date function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) generates an E_WARNING message if PHP does not have a default timezone set (since PHP5).

You must do at least one of the following:

1. Use [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set the timezone for the current script, or
2. Use the [date.timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) configuration variable in php.ini to set the default timezone for all your scripts

Pick your timezone from the [List of Supported Timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).